# Linux getent automount?

Tags: centos, automounting, ldap, sssd, getent

I just got a user account on a server with its nsswitch pointing at ldap.

Something is wrong with my home folder (I don't have one).

Generally the home folders are mounted by automount/autofs and the automount maps are in ldap.

In the bad old days of NIS it would have been as easy as `ypcat auto.home | grep myusername` to verify if the automount map had sane data.

In Solaris they seem to have [similar features](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E38254/gmrnf.html) built into `getent`.

How can I query the automount maps in CentOS 6 type Linux?

I do not have ldapsearch available, nor do I know what ldap server I'm using or how the catalog is structured. So I don't think manual ldap queries is much of an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seem to describe configured automount maps in a way that alleviates the need to learn ldap. You might need to be `root` for it to work.

```
automount --dumpmaps
```